# Branch in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I don't understand why this doesn't get compiled:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int I1,int ...Is>
int getProdSeq() {

    if(sizeof...(Is)==0)
        return I1;
    else
        return I1*getProdSeq<Is...>();
}

int main() {

    int i = getProdSeq<9,7,8>();
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

In the last recursive call to the function, `...IS` should be empty, so the first if-branch should be taken. The compiler also confirms this (that `...IS` is empty):

`main.cpp: In instantiation of 'int getProdSeq() [with int I1 = 8; int ...Is = {}]':`

But the compiler also spits out following error:

`main.cpp:5:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:36: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'I1'`

Well this error would make sense if the function was indeed called with an empty parameter-pack, but this shouldn't be the case as I circumvent this problem with the first if-statement. Why is the compiler still checking the else branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in instantiating

```
 template<int I1,int ...Is>
 int getProdSeq() {
```

The `...Is` parameter pack is empty, then the following call:

```
    getProdSeq<Is...>();
```

Instantiates `getProdSeq<>` which, of course does not exist. Just because the preceding `if` statement will never execute it, doesn't mean that it still must be compilable. The result of a template expansion must be valid C++ code, and this is not. Just because the `if` statement's `else` clasuse will never get executed doesn't change the fact that whatever's inside `else` must still be valid C++ code.

One way to do this is to use two templates:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int I1>
int getProdSeq() {

       return I1;
}

template<int I1,int I2, int ...Is>
int getProdSeq() {

        return I1*getProdSeq<I2, Is...>();
}

int main() {

    int i = getProdSeq<9,7,8>();
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It fails to compile because:

1. The function is not declared as `constexpr`.
2. The `if` statement is not compile time evaluated, hence the compiler has to generate both branches, resulting in the compiler error. That can be solved with C++17 `if contexpr`.

Example (compiled with `gcc-7 -std=gnu++1z`):

```
template<int I1, int ...Is>
constexpr int getProdSeq() {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Is)==0)
        return I1;
    else
        return I1*getProdSeq<Is...>();
}
```

Comment: So, no chance for this code to work (unless you completely change it) without the second `c++17` `constexpr`?

Answer (score 0):

> Well this error would make sense if the function was indeed called with an empty parameter-pack, but this shouldn't be the case as I circumvent this problem with the first if-statement. Why is the compiler still checking the else branch?

All your code passes all phases of the compiler up to the optimization steps. For example, for clang/llvm the branches would probably only be eliminated after conversion to the IR.
Thus, the type-checking/deduction/... fails somewhere prior to the "bad code" being discarded.

So imagine you wrote

```
int x;
if (false) {
    x = '123';
} else {
    x = 0;
}
```

This would still be wrong, even though the if-branch would never execute.